# How to create an array depending on an argument in a clear and readable way?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my problem :

I want to create an array in a very clear and readable way, so that the reader can instantly know the elements of the array.

When the array is fixed, then it is easy and very clear :

```java
    String[] columns = new String[] { "unit", "file_row", "unit_row", "content" };
    String[] types = new String[] { "INTEGER", "INTEGER", "INTEGER", "TEXT" };
```

But I also have variable arrays, depending on an argument :

```java
    // Is an argument of my method, containing the variable elements of the future array
    String[] method_arg = new String[] {"key1", "key2"};

    // The clear and readable way doesn't work anymore
    String[] columns = new String[] { "unit", method_arg, "hash"};
    String[] types = new String[] { "INTEGER", method_arg_types, "INTEGER"};

    // And the ways that work are ... much less readable
    String[] columns = new String[] {"unit"};
    columns = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(columns), Arrays.stream(method_arg)).toArray(String[]::new);
    columns = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(columns), Arrays.stream(new String[] {"hash"})).toArray(String[]::new);

    // Awkward
    String[] types = new String[method_arg.length + 2];
    Arrays.fill(types, "TEXT");
    types[0] = "INTEGER";
```

How do you make it so that the code stay clear and readable ?
The code is rather flexible, using lists should not be a problem, I'd prefer to avoid using non standard libraries though.
Also, I know a solution would be to create a method to create those arrays, like

```java
    join_arrays(new String[] {"unit"}, method_arg, new String[] {"hash"});
```

But if there are solutions making the code clear and avoiding the creation of a dedicated function, it would be better. If not I will fall back on this option.

Thank you, have a nice day !

Comment: You seem to use arrays extensively and all values I see here are based on strings. I don't even see what the code is *supposed* to do. However, you are not using objects, but Java is an object-oriented language. You should study the basics of it.

Comment: @MCEmperor I made two typos, maybe that is why you didn't see what the code does. And really, it doesn't do much, I just want to join several strings, an array of string, and several strings again in a single array of string, in a clean and readable way.

My code does do that, but in a not readable way.

As for objects, I use them, don't worry about that, but for more complicated things than makings arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually end up using a custom method for this sort of problem:

```
private <T> T[] makeArray(T... elements) {
    return elements;
}
```

Your example would look like:

```
String[] columns = makeArray("unit", method_arg, "hash");
String[] types = makeArray("INTEGER", method_arg_types, "INTEGER");
```

Comment: Is `elements` == `args`? Are you aware that you could return `elements` immediately (see my answer)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It doesn't work on my problem, because method_arg is an Array (it could be a List or anything containing several String). But with all your answers I guess there is no pretty solution already made-up in Java and that using a custom method is the cleanest way. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think you misinterpret the clarity and readability of code. First of all, you are completely RIGHT that clarity and readability of code are of the highest value. However, it doesn't mean that a reader should see immediately the outcome of the code - in your case the contents of the array. It means that the reader can clearly see first - WHAT the code does and second - HOW it does it. There are many ways to insure clarity.

- Break your longer methods to shorter ones preferably 4 - 5 lines but at the most no longer than 10 - 15. Make sure that each method deals only with a single logically indivisible issue.
- Make sure that method name is informative
- The number of parameters is kept to a minimum (0 - 3)
- The names and order of parameters are meaningful.
- Return value matches the purpose of the method.

This, of course, is not a full list.

Answer (score 0):

Java has an easier way for this, which is imho a little bit easier and is compiled away :-)

Example usage, similar to other suggestion:

```java
private static void method(String method_arg, String method_arg_types) {
    String[] columns = array("INTEGER", method_arg, "INTEGER");
    String[] types = array("INTEGER", method_arg_types, "INTEGER");
}
```

The implementation is far easier, as a side effect of how var-args are implemented.

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> T[] array(T... values) {
    return values;
}
```

Its also implemented in [org.assertj.core.util](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/util/Arrays.html#array(T...)), it should be part of the JDK imho :-)

Comment: Does it work with method_arg being an Array (or anything being more than one String) ?
The whole problem here is to join together in an Array :
several string, the array passed as argument and several string again.
But your solution only works for a single String and not an Array/List of String.

Comment: Its works for the examples you mentioned, it works for 1 till n strings. so `array("1")` works but also `array("1", "2", "3")`

Comment: As far as I understood your example I missed that `method_arg` was also an array. And that you want to join `"string", array, "string"`. It could ofcourse be adapted to support a single string followed by an array followed by var-args argument. But given these type of requirements I feel that the answer of @Michael Gantman might be closer.

Comment: Yes, method_arg is an array, as shown in my example, and that is why your answer doesn't really answer the problem.

I guess I have to go with the dedicated method to do that then :(

Thank you !